# Angular convert object to array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a json that an object I try to transform into an array otherwise when I loop on it I get [object object], in my code I tried something that works but it only shows me the values of each field instead of showing me key => value.

How to display the key and values of my json in my html ?
is there a better way to convert an object to an array ?

**json**

```
{
  "toto": [
    "titi",
    "tata"
  ],
"foo": [
    "foobar",
    "footix"
  ]
}
```

**ts.file**

```
fetchPosts() {
    let resp = this.summaryService.getAllSummery()
      this.sub = resp.subscribe((res: Isummary[]) => {
        this.summaryArray = res
      });
  }
```

**interface**

```
export interface Isummary {
  toto:string[],
  foo:string[]
}
```

**html**

```
<div*ngFor="let post of summaryArray | keyvalue">
   <span>{{post.key}}</span>
   <span *ngfor="let value of post.value">{{ value }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `summaryArray`'s type is `Isummary[]` which an object type. So you are trying to loop on a Object Array, I guess it's normal if it display "object Object" in your html. If you want to display values which are inside, try with a second ngFor and use keyvalue pipe : https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: i already try keyvalue pipe but i don't like this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) and you don't have to change anything in the object

```
export interface Isummary {
  toto: string[];
  foo: string[];
}

@Component({
  selector: "example",
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
      <span>key: {{ item.key }}</span>

      <span>Values</span>
      <span *ngFor="let value of item.value">{{ value }}</span>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  object: Isummary = {
    toto: ["titi", "tata"],
    foo: ["foobar", "footix"],
  };
}
```

or you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
@Component({
  selector: "example",
  template: `<div *ngFor="let item of object">
    <span>key: {{ item[0] }}</span>

    <span>Values</span>
    <span *ngFor="let value of item[1]">{{ value }}</span>
  </div>`,
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  object = Object.entries({
    toto: ["titi", "tata"],
    foo: ["foobar", "footix"],
  });
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to add the values ? because the json is an example I have in real json more than 2000 values and the other question how you loop on it in the html to have key and values?

Comment: I updated my code with the keyvalue pipe but for the value it doesn't work

Comment: can you give an example on stackblitz?

Comment: my example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xlrlww?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I'm a bit of a beginner, I don't know how to do it yet, but I did the same as you except 
`the const object: Isummary = {
  toto: ["titi", "tata"],
  foo: ["foobar", "footix"],
};  `
because the data comes from a json that I call via a service and there is a lot of data in the real json I can't put it like that right?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Chris is the Angular way of doing it. Here is another approach from the js only side.

Assume we have:

```json
{
  "toto": [
    "titi",
    "tata"
  ],
"foo": [
    "foobar",
    "footix"
  ]
}
```

You can use this, to transform it into an array:

```js
const toArray = (data) => {
  return Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]); 
}
```

In the end it should look like this:

```json
[
  [
    "titi",
    "tata"
  ],
  [
    "foobar",
    "footix"
  ]
]
```

Comment: where are the keys ? I need to display key and values